# What is the principle of unique key index ？

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, sqlite, relational-database

How does unique key index implemented?

As I considered , if a column is defined as unique key, then every insert should first search the whole column.

If I want to implement it by Java,I could use one kind of Set.If I load the  unique key index when I start the database, I think the memory should contain a large Set.

EDIT: As I know , database split a big table into small table/block to store,so I should collect all the small table's distinct values into one big  Set?

Comment: If you're trying to implement some kind of homebrew database engine in memory, don't do that. Use one of the existing well-established tools for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Like most things it depends on the database engine.

In PostgreSQL a `unique` index is a b-tree index. PostgreSQL looks up the index to see if an entry for the key already exists and reports an error if it does.

It's a bit more complicated than that due to the concurrency requirements and transactional inserts/rollbacks, but that's the general idea. It doesn't scan the whole column, it just does a b-tree search.

So say you try to insert id=1410.

PostgreSQL looks up the relevant b-tree index. It finds three nodes with value ranges (0-499), (500-999) and (1000-1499). It follows the 3rd one and finds five nodes under it with values (1000-1099),(1100-1199),...(1400-1499). So it descends the 1400-1499 node, and so on down until it finds a leaf node with the key... or doesn't.

If you were doing this in memory, you'd probably use a set backed by a b-tree (maybe a red/black tree). So a TreeSet might be the closest built-in data structure to what you want. You'd need to do locking around the tree to handle concurrent access.

Comment: Of course it's the concurrency and transactional issues that make this so difficult to implement outside of the database.

Comment: Thank you very much ! As I know , database split a big table into small table to store,so I should collect all the small table's distinct values into one TreeSet?

Comment: @guotong1988 If you're talking about partitioning, if you want uniqueness across partitions then yes you'd need one hash. But really, if you're dealing with more than trivial data sets, **use the database**, don't try to DIY this in application code.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Totally agree. It's simple enough for simple atomic changes where you can use locking, but if you have multi-operation transactions etc... well, that's why we have databases.

Comment: It would be interesting and useful to know what problem you are trying to solve, @guotong1988

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that every insert shall do a full scan of the column. Instead it searches small set of values (distinct values).
First of all I would suggest not to replicate the same in JAVA due to possible large set of data (if the cardinality is low, you could have very big dataset to search for which may result in OOM errors in JAVA).

But if you are sure that dataset is small, then create for example usage array, where you store key and usage flags to check.